# How to marked only one of the menu items in Extjs menu checked

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a menu added to a button.

```
buttons.push({
        iconCls: 'fa fa-money',
        text: 'Currency format',
        menu: new Ext.menu.Menu(
        {
            items: [{
                iconCls: 'fa fa-euro',
                text: '1.000,00',
                checked: true,
                handler: function (btn) {
                    updateNumericFormat(btn);
                }
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'fa fa-dollar',
                text: '1,000.00',
                checked: false,
                handler: function (btn) {
                    updateNumericFormat(btn);
                }
            }],

        })
    });
```

I would like to select only one item in the menu at the time.  so if the first item is checked I want the other item to be unchecked. but I can't get it to work.

```
updateNumericFormat: function (btn) {
    //uncheck the other button
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24g2)

```
updateNumericFormat: function (btn) {
      btn.up().down('[name=euro]').setChecked(!btn.checked , true);
}
```

Full code,

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            width: 100,
            margin: '0 0 10 0',
            floating: false, // usually you want this set to True (default)
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(), // usually rendered by it's containing component
            items: [{
                iconCls: 'fa fa-euro',
                text: '1.000,00',
                checked: true,
                name : 'euro',
                handler: function (btn) {
                   btn.up().down('[name=dollar]').setChecked(!btn.checked , true);
                }
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'fa fa-dollar',
                text: '1,000.00',
                checked: false,
                name: 'dollar',
                handler: function (btn) {
                      btn.up().down('[name=euro]').setChecked(!btn.checked , true);
                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching is the [`menucheckitem`'s](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.menu.CheckItem.html) [`group`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.menu.CheckItem.html#cfg-group) config, or maybe even a [`cycle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.button.Cycle.html) button.